# Importing modules in Workbox + Webpack custom Service Worker

Tags: vue.js, webpack, service-worker, vue-cli, workbox

I'm using the vue-cli + Webpack + Workbox setup (i.e. the setup uses register-service-worker).
I have setup my vue.config.js to use a custom service worker.
I want to import modules (e.g. auth, api wrappers etc) into my custom service worker, but I get the "Cannot use import outside a module" error.

I tried importScripts but the files are not available once webpack executes, so that fails as well.

My goal: import modules into my custom service worker, and be able to test it on the "num run serve" devServer before I can deploy.

p.s. To get my dev server to load the custom service worker I had to use `--mode production` in the scripts section of package.json .. this disabled HRM but it was still useful as I can debug my custom SW. Now I'm stuck with the imports.

Any help would be hugely appreciated!

Comment: Did you try [dynamic import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#dynamic_import)?

Comment: According to [this](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1SeQ085YdBTtW3D_ygSpO0Wz2DAe8QiS1gj37IG5lstg/edit) dynamic imports are not supported in Service Workers yet. However, according to [this](https://web.dev/es-modules-in-sw/) static imports _should_  be supported, and that's not working for me either. Lastly, I did try dynamic import, and got this error:  TypeError: import() is disallowed on ServiceWorkerGlobalScope by the HTML specification. See https://github.com/w3c/ServiceWorker/issues/1356

Comment: Are you using injectManifest mode in vue pwa config? I think the import should be handled by webpack.

Comment: Hi Allan, yes, I am using ```workboxPluginMode: 'InjectManifest',```

Comment: As per the links above, the import "should" work in the later versions of Chrome, but it doesn't .. Hoping someone can help here, as I don't want to duplicate code between my main Vue App and the service worker